# Custom Data in Drupal Views

Tags: drupal-views

I'm struggling for custom fields to appear in my Drupal views. They just aren't. I've populated my CiviCRM tables into the Drupal settings table, but they just aren't appearing.

Standard fields appear fine. It's just custom ones.

Please can anyone tell me a) if they've experienced the same thing lately? and b) where I should start debugging?

Should I be using CiviCRM Entity for this? Never needed to before.

Thanks,

John

Comment: shouldn't need civicrm entity - are your tables in single db or one for drupal and one for civi - in which case you need to add the prefix 'stuff' in settings.php

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've done the prefix stuff in settings.php but the custom fields - only the custom ones - aren't appearing in the list. Any suggestions for how I can debug this?

Comment: Just to be clear, you put the info into settings.php after creating the custom data fields in Civi, correct? I once added a custom field a few months after installation and couldn't figure out for the life of me why Views wasn't finding it... I hadn't redone the settings file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [CRM-19545](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19545)  There was a a regression introduced in 4.7.14 and fixed in 4.7.17  If you want the fix sooner see https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/pull/417/files

Comment: This is the correct answer. It was bugged.

Comment: How can I apply this bug fix as a patch?

Comment: @Christia the preferred option now would be to upgrade to the latest (4.7.23) which includes this fix and numerous others.  Is there a reason why you can't upgrade?

Comment: Yes of course. I have to wait until launch time so that I can bring over the data from a legacy database in the version it's in (4.7.15). I did end up doing a test upgrade and it didn't end up solving the problem for me.

Comment: In that case, see https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/pull/417/files  Edit modules/views/components/civicrm.core.inc on your system, find the lines that are highlighted on the left starting at line 2942 and change them to match those highlighted on the right.  Note that the +- symbols in the first column show what has been changed and do not appear in the source file.   But ... if you have already tried a test upgrade without success then you may have a different problem.